# Encounter 0 when calculating log power spectrum

Tags: frequency-spectrum

To convert power spectrum to a log-scaled one, how to define `log10(X(k))` if `X(k)=0` for some `k`?

For sake of illustration, I brief my process as follows which is a convention one:

1. Calculate the magnitude spectrum `X(k)` of the time-domain signal `x(n)` by `X(k) = abs(fft(x(n)))`.
2. Convert the magnitude spectrum or power spectrum to db by `20*log10(X(k))` or `10*log10(X(k)**2)`, respectively.

My problem arises when there is `X(k)=0` when computing `log10(X(k))` which is either not defined or `-inf`. How to deal with this?

Comment: What simulation software you use?

Comment: It is the function [`spectrum`](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/reference/std_Spectrum.html) from the library called Essentia that I used to calculate the magnitude spectrum.

Comment: If you want to avoid -inf in your answer, please add a very small value, say 1*e-20, to the zero coefficients.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like a doable solution. But does the literature solve the problem this way? Because taking `log` of `X(k)` is essential in the field of signal processing, e.g, MFCC.

Comment: The literature does not solve the problem this way. BTW, it is not a problem  I guess, you just display the log power spectrum with - infinity. May I know for what reason you want to avoid -infinity?

Comment: I want to get rid of spectrums with small energy in the spectrogram, usually are the last few frames. To this end, I tend to sum up `10*log10(X(k))` for each frame (spectrum) in the spectrogram and obtain a curve of energy or loudness `E(n)`, where `n` is the frame index. From which I calculate the standard deviation and set the threshold as `2*std` away from `mean`. That is, frames with loudness `E(n_i) = sum(10*log10(X(k)))` lower than `mean(E(n))-2*std(E(n))` will be removed. So `-inf` will result in unreasonable threshold value.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, one's data has some sort of noise floor (-96 dB, etc.).  So one common way to deal with the FFT bins that are zero (or tiny) is to replace anything below the noise floor with the noise floor level, since any value below that value is most likely not useful data.  Doing this before taking the log() function may provide some computational efficiency.

Comment: Thank you. So simply adding 1e-12 to the bins, i.e., `log10(X(k)+1e-12)` as suggested by @Oliver, is what you meant?

Comment: Depends.  Is 1e-12 around the noise floor of you data?  If not, perhaps a much larger value might do.  Around -96 dB is closer to 1e-5 ; but it depends on the scaling of your data and FFT as well as the S/N.

Comment: rather than replace, i would simply add a small number like $10^{\frac{-120}{10}}$ to the square magnitude or power spectrum.  add it to all bins before the $\log()$.